# celery zombie threads problem when using docker-compose

Tags: python, bash, docker, docker-compose, celery

I'm facing a Weird problem by docker-compose. I'm sure there is something I missed but I don't know where it is.

the problem is:

if I run

```bash
docker-compose up -d app_name
```

top command shows that a lots of zombie threads being created from the docker container

but if i simply run

```bash
docker-compose run -d app_name
```

and then run the command in container no zombie threads find by system

here is the docker-compose.yml

```yaml
celery-beat-server:
    container_name: app_name
    image: image_name
    command: bash -c "celery -A tasks worker --concurrency=1 --max-tasks-per-child=1 -l info -Q loonbeat"
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
```

the command that i run in container

```bash
bash -c "celery -A tasks worker --concurrency=1 --max-tasks-per-child=1 -l info -Q loonbeat --detach"
```

more-info: the task running by celery is using webdriver and selenium to get html page, and I do driver.close() everytime after job done.

#### update

I was able to start service fine with specific entrypoint

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
entrypoint: ./docker-entrypoint.sh
```

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# docker-entrypoint.sh
celery -A tasks worker --concurrency=1 --max-tasks-per-child=1 -l info -Q loonbeat
```

no zombie threads happened and everything works file but no clue for this